# ubuntu 16.04 I lost everything after using command apt-get -f install

Tags: apt

I used command apt-get -f install 
and something happened.
Ubuntu asked me should it start and I typed yes do as I say! 
and I lost every dependencies and all the packages are broken.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
p3at@p3at-CFSZ6-2L:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 account-plugin-facebook : Depends: libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth but it is not installed or
                                    ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not installed
 account-plugin-flickr : Depends: libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth but it is not installed or
                                  ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not installed
 account-plugin-google : Depends: libaccount-plugin-google but it is not installed or
                                  ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not installed
 adduser : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.6.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: passwd (>= 1:4.1.5.1-1.1ubuntu6) but it is not installed
 adwaita-icon-theme : Depends: libgtk-3-bin but it is not installed
                      Depends: librsvg2-common but it is not installed
 alsa-base : Depends: kmod (>= 17-1) but it is not installed
             Depends: udev but it is not installed
             Recommends: alsa-utils but it is not installed
 apparmor:amd64 : Depends: python3:any
 apport : Depends: python3 but it is not installed
          Depends: python3-gi but it is not installed
          Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 (>= 1.29.17) but it is not installed
          Recommends: policykit-1 but it is not installed
          Recommends: python3-systemd but it is not installed
 apport-gtk : Depends: python3 but it is not installed
              Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (>= 3.1.90) but it is not installed
              Depends: gir1.2-wnck-3.0 but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-gi but it is not installed
              Depends: procps but it is not installed
              Depends: x-terminal-emulator
              Recommends: update-notifier
              Recommends: gdb but it is not installed or
                          gdb-minimal but it is not installable
 apt : Depends: gpgv but it is not installed or
                gpgv2 but it is not installed
       Depends: gnupg but it is not installed or
                gnupg2 but it is not installed
 aptdaemon : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.2~)
             Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 but it is not installed
             Depends: python3-gi but it is not installed
             Depends: policykit-1 but it is not installed
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.7.4-2ubuntu2) but it is not installed
            Depends: libboost-iostreams1.58.0 but it is not installed
            Depends: libcwidget3v5 but it is not installed
            Depends: libncursesw5 (>= 6) but it is not installed
            Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.6.1) but it is not installed
            Depends: libxapian22v5 but it is not installed
 apturl:amd64 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                Depends: software-properties-gtk:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: python3-aptdaemon:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:amd64 but it is not installable
 apturl-common:amd64 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                       Depends: python3-update-manager:amd64 but it is not installable
 aspell-en : Depends: aspell (>= 0.60.3-2) but it is not installed
 bash-completion : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but it is not installed
                   Depends: bash (>= 3.2) but it is not installed
 bzip2-doc : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) but it is not installed or
                      install-info but it is not installed
 bzr : Depends: python-bzrlib (<= 2.7.0-2ubuntu3.1.1~) but it is not installed
       Depends: python-bzrlib (>= 2.7.0-2ubuntu3.1) but it is not installed
       Depends: python:any
       Recommends: python-gpgme but it is not installed
 ca-certificates : Depends: openssl (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
 ca-certificates-java : Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless but it is not installed or
                                 java7-runtime-headless
 checkbox-converged : Depends: plainbox-provider-checkbox but it is not installed
                      Depends: python3 but it is not installed
                      Depends: qml-module-qtquick-layouts but it is not installed
                      Depends: qmlscene but it is not installed
                      Depends: qtdeclarative5-dev-tools but it is not installed
                      Depends: qtdeclarative5-test-plugin but it is not installed
                      Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
 cheese:amd64 : Depends: gnome-video-effects:amd64 but it is not installable
 cheese-common : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not installed or
                          gsettings-backend
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 : Depends: xbase-clients:amd64 but it is not installable
 cmake:amd64 : Depends: cmake-data:amd64 (= 3.5.1-1ubuntu3) but it is not installable
 colord:amd64 : Depends: colord-data:amd64 but it is not installable
 compiz : Depends: compiz-core (>= 1:0.9.12.3+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
          Depends: compiz-plugins-default (>= 1:0.9.12.3+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
          Depends: compiz-gnome but it is not installed
 compiz-gnome:amd64 : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 (>= 3.4.2-0ubuntu9) but it is not installable
 console-setup-linux : Depends: kbd (>= 1.15-1ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 debconf : PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4) but it is not installed
           Recommends: apt-utils (>= 0.5.1) but it is not installed
 debconf-i18n : Depends: liblocale-gettext-perl but it is not installed
                Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not installed
                Depends: libtext-charwidth-perl but it is not installed
 debhelper : Depends: perl but it is not installed
             Depends: file (>= 3.23) but it is not installed
             Depends: dpkg (>= 1.16.2) but it is not installed
             Depends: binutils but it is not installed
             Depends: man-db (>= 2.5.1-1) but it is not installed
 dh-python : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 dh-strip-nondeterminism : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 dictionaries-common : Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not installed
 doc-base : Depends: libuuid-perl but it is not installed
 dpkg-dev : Depends: bzip2 but it is not installed
            Depends: xz-utils but it is not installed
            Depends: patch (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
            Depends: make
            Depends: binutils but it is not installed
            Depends: base-files (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installed
            Recommends: gcc but it is not installed or
                        c-compiler
            Recommends: build-essential but it is not installed
            Recommends: fakeroot
            Recommends: gnupg but it is not installed or
                        gnupg2 but it is not installed
            Recommends: gpgv but it is not installed or
                        gpgv2 but it is not installed
 emacs : Depends: emacs24 or
                  emacs24-lucid but it is not installed or
                  emacs24-nox but it is not installed
 emacs24-bin-common:amd64 : Depends: emacs24-common:amd64 (= 24.5+1-6ubuntu1.1) but it is not installable
 emacs24-common : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) but it is not installed or
                           install-info but it is not installed
 emacs24-common-non-dfsg : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) but it is not installed or
                                    install-info but it is not installed
 evince:amd64 : Depends: evince-common:amd64 (>= 3.18) but it is not installable
                Depends: evince-common:amd64 (< 3.19) but it is not installable
 evince-common : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not installed or
                          gsettings-backend
 evolution-data-server:amd64 : Depends: evolution-data-server-common:amd64 (= 3.18.5-1ubuntu1.2) but it is not installable
 evolution-data-server-common : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not installed or
                                         gsettings-backend
 evolution-data-server-online-accounts:amd64 : Depends: evolution-data-server-common:amd64 (= 3.18.5-1ubuntu1.2) but it is not installable
 fonts-kacst : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not installed
 fonts-kacst-one : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not installed
 fonts-lato : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not installed
 fonts-nanum : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but it is not installed
 fonts-sil-abyssinica : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not installed
 fonts-takao-pgothic : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not installed
 foomatic-db-compressed-ppds : Depends: python3 but it is not installed
                               Depends: xz-utils but it is not installed
                               Recommends: cups-filters (>= 1.0.42) but it is not installed or
                                           foomatic-filters (>= 4.0)
                               Recommends: ghostscript but it is not installed
                               Recommends: cups but it is not installed
                               Recommends: cups-client but it is not installed
 friendly-recovery : Depends: upstart but it is not installed or
                              systemd-sysv but it is not installed
                     Depends: whiptail but it is not installed
                     Recommends: gettext-base but it is not installed
 gazebo7:amd64 : Depends: ruby:amd64 but it is not installable
 gconf2:amd64 : Depends: python3:any
 gdebi-core : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
              Depends: python3-apt but it is not installed
              Depends: file but it is not installed
 gedit:amd64 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
               Depends: gedit-common:amd64 (>= 3.18) but it is not installable
               Depends: gedit-common:amd64 (< 3.19) but it is not installable
 gedit-common : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not installed or
                         gsettings-backend
                Recommends: gedit but it is not installed
 ghostscript:amd64 : Depends: gsfonts:amd64 (>= 6.0-1) but it is not installable
 gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 git:amd64 : Depends: liberror-perl:amd64 but it is not installable
 git-core : Depends: git (> 1:1.7.0.2) but it is not installed
 glib-networking : Depends: glib-networking-services (>= 2.48.2-1~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not installed
                   Depends: glib-networking-services (< 2.48.2-1~ubuntu16.04.1.1~) but it is not installed
 gnome-menus:amd64 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.1~)
 gnome-orca : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not installed or
                       gsettings-backend
              Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
              Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 but it is not installed
              Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (>= 3.6.2) but it is not installed
              Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 but it is not installed
              Depends: gir1.2-wnck-3.0 but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-brlapi (>= 0.5.1) but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-cairo but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-gi (>= 3.10) but it is not installed
              Depends: speech-dispatcher (>= 0.8) but it is not installed
              Recommends: xbrlapi but it is not installed
              Recommends: libgail-common but it is not installed
 gnome-power-manager:amd64 : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 (>= 3.2) but it is not installable
 gnome-settings-daemon-schemas : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not installed or
                                          gsettings-backend
 gnome-software:amd64 : Depends: aptdaemon:amd64 but it is not installable
                        Depends: gnome-software-common:amd64 (= 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.12) but it is not installable
 gnome-terminal:amd64 : Depends: gnome-terminal-data:amd64 (>= 3.18) but it is not installable
                        Depends: gnome-terminal-data:amd64 (< 3.19) but it is not installable
 gnome-user-guide : Depends: yelp (>= 3) but it is not installed
 gnome-video-effects : Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good but it is not installed
 google-mock:amd64 : Depends: python:any
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not installed or
                                      gsettings-backend
 gsettings-ubuntu-schemas : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not installed or
                                     gsettings-backend
 gvfs-common : Depends: desktop-file-utils but it is not installed
               Recommends: gvfs but it is not installed
 hardening-includes : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                      Depends: make
                      Depends: binutils but it is not installed
 hplip:amd64 : Depends: hplip-data:amd64 (= 3.16.3+repack0-1) but it is not installable
               Depends: python3-pexpect:amd64 but it is not installable
               Depends: python3-reportlab:amd64 but it is not installable
               Recommends: printer-driver-postscript-hp:amd64 but it is not installable
 hplip-data : Depends: xz-utils but it is not installed
              Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 hwdata : Depends: usbutils but it is not installed
          Depends: pciutils but it is not installed
 ibus:amd64 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
              Recommends: im-config:amd64 but it is not installable
 ibus-table : Depends: ibus (>= 1.5.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 im-config : Depends: gettext-base but it is not installed
             Depends: zenity but it is not installed or
                      kde-baseapps-bin but it is not installed or
                      whiptail but it is not installed
             Recommends: whiptail but it is not installed
 imagemagick-common : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but it is not installed
 indicator-keyboard:amd64 : Depends: libgnomekbd-common:amd64 but it is not installable
 indicator-session:amd64 : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 but it is not installable
 init-system-helpers : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3) but it is not installed
 initramfs-tools-core : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (= 0.122ubuntu8.15) but it is not installed
                        Depends: busybox-initramfs (>= 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu5) but it is not installed
                        Depends: klibc-utils (>= 2.0.4-7~) but it is not installed
                        Depends: cpio but it is not installed
                        Depends: kmod but it is not installed or
                                 module-init-tools but it is not installed
                        Depends: udev but it is not installed
                        Depends: coreutils (>= 8.24) but it is not installed
 intltool-debian : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                   Depends: gettext but it is not installed
 kbd:amd64 : Depends: console-setup:amd64 but it is not installable or
                      console-setup-mini:amd64 but it is not installable
 keyboard-configuration : Depends: liblocale-gettext-perl but it is not installed
                          Depends: initscripts but it is not installed
 language-pack-en : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not installed
 language-pack-en-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not installed
 language-pack-gnome-en : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not installed
 language-pack-gnome-en-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not installed
 language-selector-common : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                            Depends: python3-apt (>= 0.7.12.0) but it is not installed
                            Depends: python3-dbus but it is not installed
                            Depends: dbus but it is not installed
                            Depends: accountsservice (>= 0.6.29-1ubuntu6) but it is not installed
 language-selector-gnome : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                           Depends: python3-gi but it is not installed
                           Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 but it is not installed
                           Depends: python3-apt but it is not installed
                           Recommends: yelp but it is not installed
 liba11y-profile-manager-data : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not installed or
                                         gsettings-backend
 libalgorithm-diff-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                          Recommends: libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl but it is not installed
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl:amd64 : Depends: libalgorithm-diff-perl:amd64 but it is not installable
 libalgorithm-merge-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libarchive-zip-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libauthen-sasl-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libboost-mpi-python1.58.0:amd64 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 libboost-python1.58-dev:amd64 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 libcgi-fast-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                    Depends: libfcgi-perl but it is not installed
 libcgi-pm-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                  Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not installed
 libclass-accessor-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                          Depends: libsub-name-perl but it is not installed
 libdigest-hmac-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libdpkg-perl : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.16.3) but it is not installed
                Depends: perl but it is not installed
                Recommends: libfile-fcntllock-perl but it is not installed
                Recommends: bzip2 but it is not installed
                Recommends: xz-utils but it is not installed
...
...
...

E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
p3at@p3at-CFSZ6-2L:~$
```

inside of /var/log/apt/history

```
Start-Date: 2020-03-12  16:53:00
Commandline: apt-get -f install
Requested-By: p3at (1000)
Install: libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 (1.1.2-0ubuntu1, automatic), libxdmcp6:i386 (1:1.1.2-1.1, automatic), libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 (2.52.2-1ubuntu0.3, automatic), libcomerr2:i386 (1.42.13-1ubuntu1.2, automatic), libkrb5-3:i386 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1, automatic), libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1, automatic), libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 (1.38.1-1, automatic), libcups2:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.10, automatic), libdbus-1-3:i386 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.5, automatic), libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.91-2~16.04.1, automatic), libxcb-xfixes0:i386 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libprotobuf-lite9v5:i386 (2.6.1-1.3, automatic), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.6, automatic), libproxy1v5:i386 (0.4.11-5ubuntu1, automatic), liblcms2-2:i386 (2.6-3ubuntu2.1, automatic), libboost-filesystem1.58.0:i386 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1, automatic), libcairo-gobject2:i386 (1.14.6-1, automatic), libsystemd0:i386 (229-4ubuntu21.27, automatic), glib-networking:i386 (2.48.2-1~ubuntu16.04.1, automatic), libpciaccess0:i386 (0.13.4-1, automatic), apt:i386 (1.2.32, automatic), libxcb-present0:i386 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libgtk-3-0:i386 (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3, automatic), libcapnp-0.5.3:i386 (0.5.3-2ubuntu1.1, automatic), libglapi-mesa:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, automatic), libpixman-1-0:i386 (0.33.6-1, automatic), libxkbfile1:i386 (1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1, automatic), libsqlite3-0:i386 (3.11.0-1ubuntu1.4, automatic), libxrender1:i386 (1:0.9.9-0ubuntu1, automatic), libbz2-1.0:i386 (1.0.6-8ubuntu0.2, automatic), libicu55:i386 (55.1-7ubuntu0.4, automatic), libelf1:i386 (0.165-3ubuntu1.2, automatic), libgpg-error0:i386 (1.21-2ubuntu1, automatic), libbsd0:i386 (0.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), zlib1g:i386 (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.3, automatic), libavahi-common-data:i386 (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3, automatic), libgmp10:i386 (2:6.1.0+dfsg-2, automatic), libavahi-common3:i386 (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3, automatic), notification-daemon:i386 (3.18.2-1, automatic), libxcursor1:i386 (1:1.1.14-1ubuntu0.16.04.2, automatic), libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 (0~git20131104-1.1, automatic), libboost-system1.58.0:i386 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1, automatic), libk5crypto3:i386 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1, automatic), libegl1-mesa:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, automatic), libxcb-shm0:i386 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libepoxy0:i386 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.16.04.2, automatic), libxcb-render0:i386 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libmircore1:i386 (0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1.1, automatic), libapt-pkg5.0:i386 (1.2.32, automatic), libx11-6:i386 (2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2.1, automatic), libexpat1:i386 (2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.5, automatic), libudev1:i386 (229-4ubuntu21.27, automatic), libsoup2.4-1:i386 (2.52.2-1ubuntu0.3, automatic), libgbm1:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, automatic), libxshmfence1:i386 (1.2-1, automatic), libwayland-client0:i386 (1.12.0-1~ubuntu16.04.3, automatic), gcc-5-base:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12, automatic), libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.91-2~16.04.1, automatic), libtiff5:i386 (4.0.6-1ubuntu0.7, automatic), libllvm6.0:i386 (1:6.0-1ubuntu2~16.04.1, automatic), libxau6:i386 (1:1.0.8-1, automatic), libatk1.0-0:i386 (2.18.0-1, automatic), libxcomposite1:i386 (1:0.4.4-1, automatic), libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 (1.38.1-1, automatic), libmirprotobuf3:i386 (0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1.1, automatic), libtinfo5:i386 (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1, automatic), libxcb1:i386 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libatspi2.0-0:i386 (2.18.3-4ubuntu1, automatic), libxi6:i386 (2:1.7.6-1, automatic), libkrb5support0:i386 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1, automatic), libpcre3:i386 (2:8.38-3.1, automatic), libmirclient9:i386 (0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1.1, automatic), libxinerama1:i386 (2:1.1.3-1, automatic), libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, automatic), libgcrypt20:i386 (1.6.5-2ubuntu0.6, automatic), libkeyutils1:i386 (1.5.9-8ubuntu1, automatic), libselinux1:i386 (2.4-3build2, automatic), liblz4-1:i386 (0.0~r131-2ubuntu2, automatic), libxrandr2:i386 (2:1.5.0-1, automatic), libjpeg8:i386 (8c-2ubuntu8, automatic), libdrm2:i386 (2.4.91-2~16.04.1, automatic), libcolord2:i386 (1.2.12-1ubuntu1, automatic), libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 (0.106-1, automatic), libxfixes3:i386 (1:5.0.1-2, automatic), libthai0:i386 (0.1.24-2, automatic), libhogweed4:i386 (3.2-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), libfontconfig1:i386 (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1, automatic), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, automatic), libgraphite2-3:i386 (1.3.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), libjpeg-turbo8:i386 (1.4.2-0ubuntu3.3, automatic), libnettle6:i386 (3.2-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), libxdamage1:i386 (1:1.1.4-2, automatic), librest-0.7-0:i386 (0.7.93-1, automatic), libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 (2.18.1-2ubuntu1, automatic), libjbig0:i386 (2.1-3.1, automatic), libxml2:i386 (2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.7, automatic), libidn11:i386 (1.32-3ubuntu1.2, automatic), libgnutls30:i386 (3.4.10-4ubuntu1.7, automatic), libnss3:i386 (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10, automatic), libedit2:i386 (3.1-20150325-1ubuntu2, automatic), libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.91-2~16.04.1, automatic), libfreetype6:i386 (2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.4, automatic), libffi6:i386 (3.2.1-4, automatic), libp11-kit0:i386 (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1, automatic), libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.91-2~16.04.1, automatic), libharfbuzz0b:i386 (1.0.1-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), libtasn1-6:i386 (4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.3, automatic), libgconf-2-4:i386 (3.2.6-3ubuntu6, automatic), libcairo2:i386 (1.14.6-1, automatic), liblzma5:i386 (5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2, automatic), libstdc++6:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12, automatic), libavahi-client3:i386 (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3, automatic), libpango-1.0-0:i386 (1.38.1-1, automatic), libxcb-dri2-0:i386 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libxkbcommon0:i386 (0.5.0-1ubuntu2.1, automatic), libsensors4:i386 (1:3.4.0-2, automatic), libnotify4:i386 (0.7.6-2svn1, automatic), libxcb-dri3-0:i386 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libpng12-0:i386 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4, automatic), libmircommon7:i386 (0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1.1, automatic), libnspr4:i386 (2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), libwayland-server0:i386 (1.12.0-1~ubuntu16.04.3, automatic), libx11-xcb1:i386 (2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2.1, automatic), libxcb-sync1:i386 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.3-1, automatic), libdatrie1:i386 (0.2.10-2, automatic), libwayland-cursor0:i386 (1.12.0-1~ubuntu16.04.3, automatic)
Upgrade: dbus-x11:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.4, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.5), libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.4, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.5), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:16.04.15, 1:16.04.17), libsqlite3-dev:amd64 (3.11.0-1ubuntu1.3, 3.11.0-1ubuntu1.4), dbus:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.4, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.5), libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.11.0-1ubuntu1.3, 3.11.0-1ubuntu1.4), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:16.04.26, 1:16.04.29), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:16.04.15, 1:16.04.17), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:16.04.26, 1:16.04.29)
Remove: update-notifier-common:amd64 (3.168.10), apt:amd64 (1.2.32), update-manager:amd64 (1:16.04.15), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.361.2), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (32.0.0.330ubuntu0.16.04.1), ubuntu-minimal:amd64 (1.361.4), apt-utils:amd64 (1.2.32), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:16.04.26), update-notifier:amd64 (3.168.10)
End-Date: 2020-03-12  16:53:36
```

Comment: I picked a requirement at random and looked (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kmod) and it's available for xenial/16.04 in a version that meets your message for that.  I'd check your software lists are up-to-date (ie. `sudo apt update`) and read the messages you get, as I supect you'll have unusual results there. If they look normal you could `apt-cache policy kmod` and I suspect you won't see what is expected (but I suspect you'll see your issue with `sudo apt-get update` output as already stated)

Comment: Hey guiverc, thank you for the comment. the thing is, I get the same result and error message when I hit those commands. the apt related command gives me the same result.

Comment: I tried to indicate that your problem should be shown in the output of `sudo apt-get update`, ie. do you see the lines you should be seeing, lines that don't belong etc..  And yes you should get the same for `apt-get update` and `apt update`; both both will be your issue. You'll also get detail from the provided apt-cache command which you could have posted...  I'd expect your sources to be your issue (ie. `/etc/apt/sources.list` related)

Comment: Thank you, if i hit the apt-cache command, it shows ```p3at@p3at-CFSZ6-2L:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-cache policy kmod
kmod:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22-1ubuntu5.2
  Version table:
     22-1ubuntu5.2 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
     22-1ubuntu5 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
     22-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
``` sorry that I have poor knowledge..

Comment: Please don't add extra detail to your question, you can edit your own questions so please place it there (it has greater formatting capabilities, plus more people see it & that may lead to quicker results for you). No need to apologize, I wasn't clear providing primarily hints.

Comment: For a long shot. `software-properties-gtk` TAB updates unlock xenial-security` if it is not. and show  `sudo apt update` please.

Comment: What did you change on your system between the last time this worked and now? It looks like you removed python3 or something like that.